# CreateProcess() in Delphi : redirect output from executable command

Tags: delphi, redirect, createprocess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the dos output. In delphi2009 with vista.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971266/how-to-get-the-dos-output-in-delphi2009-with-vista)

I am using Createprocess() in order to verify a certificate with openssl. I want to redirect the answer so that i don;t have to write it in a .txt and read it from there. I want to redirect it to a string directly. The basic code is the following:

```
CreateProcess(
    nil,
    'CMD /C C:\openssl\bin\openssl verify C:\myCA\Certificat.crt > C:\certificat\outdelphi.txt',
    nil, nil,False,
    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP+NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
    nil, 'c:\', ShowInfo, ProcInfo
);
Sleep(1000);
```

i don't want to use the >C:\certificat\outdelphi.txt. I want the output to be redirected to a string. How can i do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the dos output. In delphi2009 with vista.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971266/how-to-get-the-dos-output-in-delphi2009-with-vista) Also [How in Delphi 2009 redirect console (stin, sterr)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841047/how-in-delphi-2009-redirect-console-stin-sterr)

Comment: @David, for later performance optimization?

Comment: @Uwe Ah. Change it to Sleep(500) and release version 2 with the strap-line, "Now twice as fast!"

Comment: It is equivalent to `WaitForNoObject(1000); call`

Comment: Eew, "dos" term gives me facepalms. Also: is not really correct to link general redirection technique with problems imposed by D2009 migration (potentially breaks at least 2 points if built as unicode)